# Cannot format code on visual studio when using TypeScript

Tags: visual-studio-2017

So I'm using Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise Version 15.6.4 and Visual C# 2005 keyboard shortcuts and whenever I'm trying to format the code pressing (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>D</kbd>) on other languages than C#, I get an error saying

> "The key combination is bound to command (Format document) which is
>   not..."

such that the rest I cannot see.
I wrote code on TS before but formatted my PC, and now after reinstallation, it just happened no reason.

Error capture:

[image: Error capture]

Comment: Does it work when you do it manually through the menus?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I figured it out.
The problem was that I haven't installed any Visual Studio features that support javascript & typescript.
The solution is press "Tools" > "Get Tools and Features" > Then I marked "Universal Windows Platform development" and "Node.js development".
Click "Modify" and wait for the installation to complete. Then restart VS and it should work.